# Count median grouped by day

Tags: mysql, group-by, median

I have a script which counts median value for all table data:

```
SELECT avg(t1.price) as median_val FROM (
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as `row_number`, d.price
  FROM mediana d,  (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  WHERE 1
  ORDER BY d.price
) as t1, 
(
  SELECT count(*) as total_rows
  FROM mediana d
  WHERE 1
) as t2
AND t1.row_number>=total_rows/2 and t1.row_number<=total_rows/2+1;
```

Now I need to get median value not for all table values, but grouped by date. Is it possible? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cf27 - so as result I will get 2013-03-06 - 1.5 , 2013-03-05 - 3.5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope I didn't loose myself and overcomplicate things, but here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT sq.created_at, avg(sq.price) as median_val FROM (
SELECT t1.row_number, t1.price, t1.created_at FROM(
SELECT IF(@prev!=d.created_at, @rownum:=1, @rownum:=@rownum+1) as `row_number`, d.price, @prev:=d.created_at AS created_at
FROM mediana d, (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prev:=NULL) r
ORDER BY created_at, price
) as t1 INNER JOIN  
(
  SELECT count(*) as total_rows, created_at 
  FROM mediana d
  GROUP BY created_at
) as t2
ON t1.created_at = t2.created_at
WHERE 1=1
AND t1.row_number>=t2.total_rows/2 and t1.row_number<=t2.total_rows/2+1
)sq
group by sq.created_at
```

What I did here, is mainly just to reset the rownumber to 1 when the date changes (it's important to order by created_at) and included the date so we can group by it. In the query which calculates total rows I also included created_at, so we can join the two subqueries.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Only one comment - should be order not by created_at, but by price, because prices in database are unordered and where can be 2,5,3,6, etc. ;)

Comment: It doesn't matter if prices are ordered or not, doesn't it? But it also doesn't hurt to `ORDER BY created_at, price`, but important is, that it's ordered by created_at first, otherwise the rownum is not right.

Comment: It is very important for median value counting. If prices are - 2,3,1 and order is by date you will get median 3, but correct answer is 2. And order by date isn't necessary where, script works correct without it.

Comment: With `ORDER BY created_at, price` it should work definitely correct then. Adjusted answer.

Comment: If I would like to count the median from a subset of the table where should I put the WHERE clauses?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another take on the median inspired by this [post](http://web.performancerasta.com/metrics-tips-calculating-95th-99th-or-any-percentile-with-single-mysql-query/) using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `GROUP_CONCAT`. I am not sure about the performance on large tables relative to the method described by @fancyPants that uses row numbers, but on smaller tables (~20K rows) it works very fast.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT
    created_at,
    (
    CAST(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            price ORDER BY price SEPARATOR ','),
            ',', FLOOR((COUNT(*)+1)/2) ), ',', -1) AS DECIMAL) +
    CAST(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            price ORDER BY price SEPARATOR ','),
            ',', FLOOR((COUNT(*)+2)/2) ), ',', -1) AS DECIMAL)
    ) / 2.0 AS median_price
FROM
    mediana
GROUP BY
    created_at
;
```

Here is the output for the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cf27) given in the question (the fiddle appears to be broken, but I run this on the table shown in the fiddle within MySQL itself):

```
+------------+--------------+
| created_at | median_price |
+------------+--------------+
| 2012-03-05 |       3.5000 |
| 2012-03-06 |       1.5000 |
+------------+--------------+
```

The `GROUP_CONCAT` essentially creates a string representation of an array of prices per `created_at` date. The two `SUBSTRING_INDEX` commands then look for the middle value(s), i.e. the median. It is necessary to have two calls to the `GROUP_CONCAT` and average them to handle the case in which there are an even number of `price` elements for a single `created_at` date.

UPDATE:

It is worth mentioning that the `GROUP_CONCAT` function has a default length of 1024 bytes, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len). This may cause very long results to be truncated, which will cause a miscalculation. You can set a larger default with the command `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = N;` where `N` is some other, larger value if you are concerned about large results. I have added that setting to the code snippet above. I chose 1000000, but you could use another value as well.

You can also spot check your results using `COUNT(*)` and `OFFSET` with one of your `GROUP BY` values. For example,

1. First get the count of the number of rows for a specific `GROUP BY` value,

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mediana WHERE created_at = '2012-03-06';`

2. Let `X` be the number of rows you get from step 1. Divide `X` by 2 to get half its value, `Y`.
3. Use the value `Y` as an offset to find the median.

   a. If `Y` was a whole number then do both

   `SELECT price FROM mediana WHERE created_at = '2012-03-06' ORDER BY price LIMIT 1 OFFSET (Y-1);`

   and

   `SELECT price FROM mediana WHERE created_at = '2012-03-06' ORDER BY price LIMIT 1 OFFSET Y;`

   and average the two results to get the median value.

   b. If `Y` was a decimal, then round `Y` down to the nearest whole number (call it `W`) and use that as a single offset,

   `SELECT price FROM mediana WHERE created_at = '2012-03-06' ORDER BY price LIMIT 1 OFFSET W;`

   and this will be your median value.