# MySQL function - save multiple round trips

Tags: mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a function in Mysql - the definition looks like

```
CREATE FUNCTION `compute_average`(roleId BIGINT, testType VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS double

SET @ct := (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM activiti
WHERE
  AND test_type = testType
  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, started_on, completed_on) <= 1209600
  AND role_id = roleId);

SET @row_id := 0;
SET @average := 0.0;

SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, started_on, completed_on)) / 3600 AS median INTO @median
FROM activiti
WHERE completed_on IS NOT NULL
AND (SELECT @row_id := @row_id + 1)
    BETWEEN @ct/2.0 AND @ct/2.0 + 1
ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, started_on, completed_on)
LIMIT 1;

RETURN @average;
```

This mysql function is supposed to count average of all roles based on testType. (Actual logic is much complex, some 20 lines of code. It does some computation, too. Not just AVG)

I have 20 testType parameters, and I call this function from my hibernate code with raw query as

```
SELECT compute_average(?, ?);
```

Now, the question is, because I have 20 different test Types, I make this call 20 times.

I am trying to save these 20 roundtrips. Initially I thought of using groupBy, but It appears that you cannot return tuple from mysql function.

Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: you can return a string (`text`) where values are concatenated in a well-defined fashion, basically emulating a tuple

Comment: oh.. I did not think about it! Let me give a try

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya do you have any example of such conversion I can refer to?

Comment: Think `Group_concat()` with `Concat()`. You will have to add some more details about your Function, in order for me to be able to give a specific answer

Comment: I was in process to add those details..

Comment: both roleId and testType are not used in your updated code.

Comment: You don't need a function at all, a simple query does the job. Here's an example of how to write such a query with group by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386799/count-median-grouped-by-day/15387675#15387675

Comment: So do you mean I should make two group by queries to do the logic this function is doing?